# Unmount data volume hosting NFS exports

Tags: nfs, unmounting, pacemaker, corosync

So I've got a customer with two NFS server setup in a pacemaker cluster active/standby configuration. It is a legacy system running RHEL6. On the servers there is /mnt/data1 which is an xfs mountpoint on a drbd mirrored disk. The mount is active on one node at a time and controlled by pacemaker (so is drbd for that matter).

My problem is in critical cases where I need to move active services to the other server without shutting down the nfs clients first. I can shutdown the NFS services, but no matter what I try, I can't unmount the /mnt/data1 filesystem as it reports as 'busy'.

I tried changing the daemon stop sequence on the nodes. Right now I have the following sequence:

- rpc.mountd
- nfsd
- exportfs -au
- rpc.statd

Both 'lsof /mnt/data1' and 'fuser -mv /mnt/data1' do not report any open files on the mountpoint and I can verify no terminal sessions are there either.  Short of having to shutdown the box (which kills any debugging I would like to do), I can't get the filesystem unmounted to allow pacemaker to cleanly move the filesystem mount to the other node.  I assume that there are some hanging file locks, but I'm not sure how else to kill them.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `umount -l -f` ?

Comment: Unmount won't do it unfortunately... Lazy unmount will just prevent new processes from being able to access the mount, but the references stay open and Force only works on NFS.  I'm afraid with a lazy unmount that an open file handle might corrupt the filesystem... Maybe I'm being too cautious.